# Dev-C++ mysql devpak installed but not working

Tags: c++, mysql, dev-c++

Trying to get C++ to communicate with a local database but running into some issues.

I am using Dev-C++, I have WAMP server installed for mysql but I have not got that far yet.

I have followed these [steps](http://www.freewebs.com/dragonstein/msql_c.html) to make sure it works.

It didn't it gave a

[Error] mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory

Assuming something was wrong with the provided code I opened the example that came with the dev pack and still

```
12  25  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\examples\libmysql\mysql.cpp  [Error] mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory
```

Checking the project properties shows the following

C and C++ compiler parameters

```
-Wall
-W
```

Linker parameters

```
-lmysql
```

Package manager verifies the data is their and I visually verified the existence of mysql folder inside include inside DevC++ directory.

Why isn't it being found? This is an example project which should work. Is there anything specific I should do to make it connect? The package is installed. The linker is being passed the parameter. I even tried copy/pasting the mysql folder into the example but it didn't change.

Windows 10, Dev-C++ 5.11, libmysql package 5.0.5, WAMP server 2.5

Comment: Did you maybe include `"mysql/mysql.h"` instead of `<mysql/mysql.h>`?

Comment: Where are the MySQL headers installed? Have you added that path to the settings?

Comment: SimonKraemer no it's <mysql/mysql.h> like I said this is a sample project that came with package :)
@Someprogrammerdude The headers are in /Dev-Cpp/Include/mysql and I have included them in the settings yes. OR not... I included them in the wrong tab.. that was it